# How do we hit enter key event after putting text into a text box in Selenium Webdriver with Ruby bindings

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know how we use enter key using send_keys:return command but I need to put text and hit enter key immediately after putting text into it. Is it possible to combine 2 events rather than 2 seperate events?

Thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send it like this:

```
b.element.send_keys "text", :enter
```

**Edit**

If I understand your scenario correctly, I think you can handle it with a wait:

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
wait.until { browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div‌​/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/di‌​v/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input") }

browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div‌​/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/di‌​v/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"2",:return
```

What I suspect is happening is that field 2 is changing after you interact with field 1.  The wait should look for field 2 for up to 10 seconds, then interact with it.

Comment: @Richard.. could you pls help me with resolving this kind of error?
` Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked`

I am trying to enter into the field which is displayed only on validating the previous field.

`browser.find_element(:xpath,"/html/body/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/input").send_keys"2",:return`

This is my code for it but, doesn't work

Comment: @user007 Best guess is that you found an element, interacted with the page in a way that caused an update, then tried to perform an action with the element.

Comment: exactly thats what is to be done. I interacted with field 1 which on validation opens up field 2.

Comment: how do we handle such events? I am badly stuck with this, tried implicit & explicit waits but that didnt help either.

Comment: @user007 I edited in an answer, although after reading your comment, you may have tried what I have suggested.

Comment: I had tried and again tried the same approach but the script fails `[remote server] resource://fxdriver/modules/web_element_cache.js:7610:in `fxdriver.cache.getElementAt': Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since last it was last looked
 up (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError)`

Comment: nopes any numerical value and then hitting enter open ups the next hidden field.

Comment: At a guess, without actually seeing your system, sending the 2 + enter is modifying the page before Selenium sends its response back to the page.

Comment: Well if we check the xpath of this new element, its the same that we are specifying in our script. And its triggered only after previous step open ups this new element.